# Pyinstaller one file local files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I try to create a one file executable that when run, reads in a config file and creates new directories with files that it continues to read to achieve its task. Unfortunately, I am having path issues as the resulting executable is unable to find those files even in same directory. I assume I have to use some sort of path finding function to properly redirect the executable code?

In my code if I do:

```
try:
    with open('conf.ini', 'r') as conf:
        # do something
except IOError:
    print('conf not found')
```

This is how my source code runs. But after creating a one file executable, it is unable to find the conf file or anything else similar.

Executable is generated using `pyinstaller --onefile code.py`.

Comment: Actually include the code here, as its not clear of the error

Comment: Sorry about that, wasn't sure if that might help.

Comment: Also include the command you used with PyInstaller

Comment: Your going one directory back from where the exe is right?Is that what you want?

Comment: Your code assumes conf.ini is in the current working directory. Try sinply printing the current working directory in your code when it starts. Is the file there?

Comment: @barny i thought it goes one directory back

Comment: @barny I just did that and apparently it returns my home directory.

Comment: @CoolCloud No, I want the executable to look for files in the same directory it is in for instance.

Comment: so shouldnt it be `open('conf.ini', 'r')` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud my bad, a typo in the question but yes. Current working directory the executable returns is my home directory instead of wherever it is located.

Comment: ‘Wherever it is located’ - do you want to package conf.ini in the onefile exe, or have it somewhere else, if so where?

Comment: `./conf.ini` is in the current working directory, same as `conf.ini`. `../conf.ini` would be one directory higher.

Comment: @barny I know of bundling but this file changes the info and bundling it will prevent that happening no? Also, the code has to generate new files and then use those files as well.

Comment: You didn’t answer: where do you want conf.ini to be located? AND, what do you want to happen if it isn’t found?

Comment: @barny My bad, I want it to be located same directory as the executable. If its not found, throw an exception.

Comment: You should read the documentation about `sys.executable` - see https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html - basically I think `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)` should be the path to use. NOTE you will have to open a different path if not running from the onefile exe, how to do this is documented at the top of that documentation page.